# Cannot call value of non-function type '((success: Bool, error: NSError?) throws -> Void)?)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I updated to Swift 2 and Xcode 7 and ran the migration tool. Then I got a ton of errors. One I'm stuck on is this

```
func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success:Bool, error:NSError?) throws -> Void)?)
{
    // 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
    let healthKitTypesToRead = (array:[
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)

        ])

    // 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
    let healthKitTypesToWrite = (array:[
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
        ])

    // 3. If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
    {
        var error = NSError.self
        if( completion != nil )
        {
            completion(success:false, error:&error)
        }
        return;
    }

    // 4.  Request HealthKit authorization
    healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite as Set<NSObject>, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead as Set<NSObject>) { (success, error) -> Void in

        if( completion != nil )
        {
            completion(success:success,error:error)
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on completion(success:false, error&error)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are calling the closure like so:

```
if completion != nil  {
    completion(success: false, error: error)
}
```

The `completion` is optional, so you would call it as:

```
completion?(success: false, error: error)
```

Note the `?`. It also eliminates the need for the `if completion != nil ...`.

--

I notice that you've defined the closure such that it throws errors. If that's really the case, then you need something like a `do`-`try`-`catch` block:

```
do {
    try completion?(success:false, error: error)
} catch let completionError {
    print(completionError)
}
```

Either that, or change the closure so that it doesn't throw errors. That's a pretty curious pattern.

--

You also have a line that says

```
var error = NSError.self
```

I don't know what your intent of that is. What error are you trying to pass back to the closure?

If you really wanted to create your own `NSError` object, you might do something like:

```
let error = NSError(domain: "com.domain.app", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : NSLocalizedString("Health Data Not Available", comment: "")])
```

Comment: Yea that fixes the first error but then it introduces a new one. 'Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSError.Type' to expected argument type 'NSError?'

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Removing the error in the closure works. I'm not 100% on the pattern for this. I'm taking over a project and this is what I'm working with. Keep an eye out for my username I'll have many more questions....

Comment: I'll look into the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a very similar error message for a completely different reason.

> Cannot call value of non-function type CLLocationCoordinate2D?

I wrote my code as such:

```
secondCoord(latitude: secondLongLat.0, longitude: secondLongLat.1)
```

Which was foolish. I was missing the constructor itself. The correct version is below.

```
secondCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: secondLongLat.0, longitude: secondLongLat.1)
```